# How to cross-compile from linux/amd64 to darwin/arm64 with cgo?

Tags: linux, macos, go, cross-compiling

I am trying to cross-compile `darwin/arm64` on `linux/amd64`, I got the below error when I build code with `CGO_ENABLED=1`, I understand the error, but I don't how to solve.

My code must enable `CGO_ENABLED` feature to compile.

ErrorMessage:

```
GOOS=darwin GOARCH=arm64 CGO_ENABLED=1 CC=gcc go build -o dist/darwin-arm64 cmd/main.go
# runtime/cgo
gcc: error: arm64: No such file or directory
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-arch'
make: *** [makefile:6: darwin] Error 2
```

Host System:

```
Linux 83433d127edb 5.13.0-28-generic #31~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jan 19 14:08:10 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Go Environment:

```
GO111MODULE=""                                                                                                                       
GOARCH="amd64"                                                                                                                       
GOBIN=""                                                                                                                             
GOCACHE="/root/.cache/go-build"                                                                                                      
GOENV="/root/.config/go/env"                                                                                                         
GOEXE=""                                                                                                                             
GOEXPERIMENT=""                                                                                                                      
GOFLAGS=""                                                                                                                           
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"                                                                                                                   
GOHOSTOS="linux"                                                                                                                     
GOINSECURE=""                                                                                                                        
GOMODCACHE="/root/go/pkg/mod"                                                                                                        
GONOPROXY=""                                                                                                                         
GONOSUMDB=""                                                                                                                         
GOOS="linux"                                                                                                                         
GOPATH="/root/go"                                                                                                                    
GOPRIVATE=""                                                                                                                         
GOPROXY="https://proxy.golang.org,direct"                                                                                            
GOROOT="/usr/lib/go-1.18"                                                                                                            
GOSUMDB="sum.golang.org"                                                                                                             
GOTMPDIR=""                                                                                                                          
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/lib/go-1.18/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"                                                                                    
GOVCS=""                                                                                                                             
GOVERSION="go1.18"                                                                                                                   
GCCGO="gccgo"                                                                                                                        
GOAMD64="v1"                                                                                                                         
AR="ar"                                                                                                                              
CC="gcc"                                                                                                                             
CXX="g++"                                                                                                                            
CGO_ENABLED="1"                                                                                                                      
GOMOD="/home/worker/go.mod"                                                                                                          
GOWORK=""                                                                                                                            
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"                                                                                                                  
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""                                                                                                                      
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"                                                                                                                
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"                                                                                                                  
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"                                                                                                                 
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"                                                                                                              
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/tmp/go-build1206945591=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches"
```

Comment: good read on the subject: https://dave.cheney.net/2016/01/18/cgo-is-not-go                 "Some people, when confronted with a problem, think “I know, I’ll use cgo.”
Now they have two problems." :)

Answer (score 2):

Chances are, you need to install the gcc toolchain for cross-compilation to `arm64`.

I know Debian/Ubuntu have cross-compiling toolchains for Windows, as well as other Linux architectures (e.g.: packages `gcc-aarch64-linux-gnu`, `libc6-dev-arm64-cross` and `gcc-mingw-w64-x86-64`).

I'm not sure if there is a `darwin` toolchain available.